# Very slow login to windows 10 in a shared computer lab

Tags: login, shared-folders, roaming-profiles

In a college we have multiple computer labs for students' use. Students use different computers every time they go the lab. The log in process is very slow (up to 10 min).

We suspect it has to do with copying profiles. Computers with the similar specifications are used by staff and there are no slowness. My questions:

- What can be done to speed up the log in process?
- Are there best practices for setting up computers in shared computer labs (i.e. roaming profile, network share, ....?

The network is 1Gbps with around a maximum of 300 concurrent users.

Comment: Your an Administrator on this network? So are you using roaming profiles? What can you tell us about the network itself? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: All switches and network interfaces are 1Gbps. Currently we use local profiles. Whenever a student use a PC he didn't use before, it creates a new local profile. We run scripts to delete profiles once a month as sizes of profiles grow a lot. In the past we used roaming profiles and that also was slow. The college size is 1500 users. We expect not more than 300 simultaneous users on the wired network.

Comment: You should [edit] your question.  1 Gbps network connection isn't that fast for 1500 users.  How many concurrent users?  Have you analyzed each segment of the network?